# Current location of uploading file not correct for Laravel getRealPath()

Tags: php, linux, laravel, nginx

There is an issue on following code which gives the wrong location for large size (Greater than 1Mb) files.

```
$file = $request->file('file');
echo $file->getRealPath();
```

Above code gives me the output for large files is "/var/www/xxxx/public" which is not expected.
But for small size files it is something like "/tmp/phpC6PcYz" which is expected.

What could be the issue? It appears to be some server configuration such as memory limit. I increased PHP memory limit up to 1Gb and still have the issue.

Comment: check `upload_max_filesize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you also need to define `upload_max_filesize`